# history.push not redirecting me to the Home

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router

So I have a Register Component, so when I try to register in the dev tools/ network I am getting user created. but for some reason, it is not pushing me to the home like it is supposed to, I think the problem might be in the `history.push("/");`. I have tried many things, but I can't seem to figure it out

App

```
function App() {


   const logoutHandler = () =>{
        localStorage.removeItem("authToken");
        history.push("/")
    }
  const [loading, setLoading]= React.useState(true)

  useEffect(()=>{
    setTimeout(() => {  
      setLoading(false)
    }, 3000);
    
  },[])
  return (
    <div >
      {!loading ?(      
      <Router>
        <Switch>
           <Route path='/cart'>
            <Header />
            <Cart/>
          </Route>       
        <Route path='/searchbook/:booksKey'>
         <Search />   
        </Route> 
        <Route path='/book/:bookKey'>
         <Header />
         <Book />      
        </Route> 
      
        <Route path='/forgotpassword'>
       <ForgotPassword />
        </Route> 
        <Route path='/passwordreset/:resetToken'>
        <ResetPassword />
        </Route> 
       <Route exact path='/register'>
        <Register />
        </Route> 
        <Route path='/login'>
         <Login />
        </Route> 
         <Route path='/'>
         <Header />
         <Home />      
        </Route> 
        </Switch>
      </Router>
       ):(
       <>
      <BookAnimation />
      </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Register

```
import { useState, useHistory  } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Link,  } from "react-router-dom";


const Register = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [confirmpassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const history = useHistory()
  const registerHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  
    const config = {
      header: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };

    if (password !== confirmpassword) {
      setPassword("");
      setConfirmPassword("");
      setTimeout(() => {
        setError("");
      }, 5000);
      return setError("Passwords do not match");
    }

    try {
      const { data } = await axios.post(
        "http://localhost:5000/api/auth/register",
        {
          username,
          email,
          password,
        },
        
        config
        
      );
    
      localStorage.setItem("authToken", data.token);

      history.push("/");
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.response) {
        setError(error.response.data.error);
      }
      setTimeout(() => {
         setError("");
      }, 5000);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="register-screen">
      <form onSubmit={registerHandler} className="register-screen__form">
        <h3 className="register-screen__title">Register</h3>
        {error && <span className="error-message">{error}</span>}
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="name">Username:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            required
            id="name"
            placeholder="Enter username"
            value={username}
            onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="email">Email:</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            required
            id="email"
            placeholder="Email address"
            value={email}
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            required
            id="password"
            autoComplete="true"
            placeholder="Enter password"
            value={password}
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="confirmpassword">Confirm Password:</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            required
            id="confirmpassword"
            autoComplete="true"
            placeholder="Confirm password"
            value={confirmpassword}
            onChange={(e) => setConfirmPassword(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
          Register
        </button>

        <span className="register-screen__subtext">
          Already have an account? <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
        </span>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Register;
```

Comment: Have you tried pushing a different path and seeing if the URL updates at least? Also, where is the history object being passed in. I don't see it being passed in through your App component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Switch` will Render the first child `<Route>` that matches the location and will stop looking for matches. According to your case the first matches will be `<Route path='/cart'>`.

Move `<Route path='/'>` to the top of routes definition. Add `exact`:

`<Route exact path='/'>`

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: Are you using react-router or react-router-dom? and is Router an alias for BrowserRouter?

Comment: I am using react-router-dom

Comment: From where are you importing history?

Comment: Use history from import { useHistory  } from "react-router-dom";

Comment: If it's not to much to ask how would I implement the logout funcionality

Comment: When the user login in your app, you can store some value (user or token) in the localStorage/other place to know if the session is active, when he press the logout option, you can clear the local storage data and change the route

Comment: I have updated the code in the App component , could that  work

Comment: Yes, it should work, also you can listen for the storage event and if the authToken was removed you can force the logout action

Comment: So if I want a specific component to be shown only when user is logged in, what could I do

Comment: Check if authToken exits and if it is valid

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `useHistory` hook:

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

function MyComponent() {
  const routerHistory = useHistory()
}
```

To navigate to a specific route use:

```
routerHistory.push('/')
```

I tend not to call the variable `history` because javascript already has a `history` variable stored in the global scope.

Comment: I am getting this eror on the line where I declare the routerHistory
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Comment: import it from ```react-router-dom``` instead of ```react-router```. (my bad)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem with the first answer is that they are trying to destructure `useHistory` from `react-router`, not `react-router-dom`.

And your code is trying to destructure `useHistory` from `react` (which won't work because `useHistory` [is not a native react hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html).)

Can you try using the hook in the following way (as supplied by the [react-router-dom docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory)):

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const Register = () => {
  // ... your other state variables ... 

  let history = useHistory();

  const headToHome() {
    history.push("/");
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={headToHome}>
      Go home
    </button>
  );
}
```

And define your root route as an exact path:

```
<Route exact path="/" />
```